# Convert timestamp to string without loosing miliseconds in Spark (Scala)

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using the following code in order to convert a date/timestamp into a string with a specific format:

```
when(to_date($"timestamp", fmt).isNotNull, date_format(to_timestamp($"timestamp", fmt), outputFormat))
```

The "fmt" is coming from a list of possible formats because we have different formats in the source data.

**The issue here is that when we apply the "to_timestamp" function, the milliseconds part is lost. Is there any other possible (and not over complicated) ways to do this without loosing the miliseconds detail?**

Thanks,

BR

Comment: converting to long before applying to_timestamp will preserve milliseconds.

Comment: @jayrythium can you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having to mess with it while back. This will work as well.

```
df = (
        spark
            .createDataFrame(['2021-07-19 17:29:36.123', 
                              '2021-07-18 17:29:36.123'], "string").toDF("ts")
            .withColumn('ts_with_mili', 
                        (unix_timestamp(col('ts'), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") 
                         + substring(col('ts'), -3, 3).cast('float')/1000).cast('timestamp'))
    ).show(truncate=False)
    
    # +-----------------------+-----------------------+
    # |ts                     |ts_with_mili           |
    # +-----------------------+-----------------------+
    # |2021-07-19 17:29:36.123|2021-07-19 17:29:36.123|
    # |2021-07-18 17:29:36.123|2021-07-18 17:29:36.123|
    # +-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: The issue is that we have several possible date formats, so probably the only way is to create a function that will apply that substring depending on each type of format. 

I believe that there is no other option

Comment: yea, multiple data formats definitely limit the options. I know there is another way to do it that's more elegant then above, if I came across it, I will post.